# Creating Bootstrap samples in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, statistics, statistics-bootstrap

I am confused about how the bootstrap samples are generated, are these values taken from the original data or some random numbers? I have variable (a) of length 700 i.e. 700 samples and I am trying to produce 100 bootstraps of 'a' and compare these 100 bootstraps with another variable (b). I am trying to use the bootstrp function of MATLAB to do this. Bootstat= bootstrp(100,@corr,a,b); Is this correct? If so, the 100 bootstraps generated will contain any random numbers or numbers from the original variable 'a'? Please help me understand this process.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you read the help of function bootstrp and about bootstraping in general? No additional random sample values are generated, instead bootstraping is based on random selection of existing values.

Comment: Yes thank you. I understand it better now.